# get a file contein form url using c language programming

Tags: c

i want to make a program that connect to online database . i made php file that shows the data , but i want to open the url and get the html source inside like :

this code in csharp :

```
   using System.Net;
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/a.html");
   }
```

this code in python :

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://example.com' # write the url here
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
print data
```

how can i write as those code in c language ?

Comment: This site is not a code translation service.

Comment: Your question is definitely OS specific.

Answer (score 1):

You want a library providing an HTTP client service. I would recommend [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for that purpose. It is usable (on most operating systems) in C code.

<sup>Standard [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) does not know about HTTP or URLs. You need to use some operating system (like [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/papers/posix_faq.html) ones, eg Linux) and some libraries.</sup>

You might alternatively wanting a library providing some HTTP server abilities. In that case, consider [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

<sup>(of course, they are other libraries for HTTP client and HTTP server tasks; GTK, Qt, Poco have something relevant)</sup>

You should understand a bit of HTTP before coding. Be sure to at least read the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) wikipage, and possibly a lot more.

You might perhaps consider something different, maybe [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) (perhaps with an [HTTP transport](http://www.simple-is-better.org/json-rpc/transport_http.html)), or [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), etc.